# Mysql JSON Data type : want to replace multiple array json value i.e update the record of nested json

Tags: php, mysql, json

in my mysql db i store the value like :

```
Table name : access_record
id | access
1  | [{"camp_id":"1","permission":"r,w","read_unread_status":"0"},
      {"camp_id":"2","permission":"r,w","read_unread_status":"0"}]
```

I want to update the record id=1 which has camp_id = 2 
& update value of read_unread_status = 1

please help me to find the solution.

I was try like below which is select query (testing):

```
SELECT id,(SELECT json_search(access->'$[*].camp_id','all',2)) FROM access_record WHERE json_search(access->'$[*].camp_id','all',2) IS NOT NULL AND id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure but try this, I will work on simple json but I have not try it on an array though.

```
UPDATE access_record SET access =JSON_SET(access, '$.read_unread_status', 1)  WHERE id=1 and JSON_EXTRACT(access, '$.camp_id') = 2;
```

Comment: thank u for replay.... but my access record json is the array json i.e. 2d associative array in json format...

Answer (score 0):

There is a `JSON_REPLACE()` function in MySQL:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-replace

Untested code (I am not sure about the first parameter `json_doc`):

```
SELECT JSON_REPLACE(@j, '$.read_unread_status', '1')
FROM access_record
WHERE json_search(access->'$[*].camp_id','all',2) IS NOT NULL AND id=1
```

Side note: are you sure `read_unread_status` should be a string instead of a boolean or number?